# Verifying a fact about Connectedness

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Munkres gives a proof of the following claim, I'm just checking if mine is okay:

> Let $A$ be a connected subspace of $X$. If $A \subset B \subset \overline{A}$, then $B$ is also connected.

Pf:
$A$ is connected so it is closed. Thus $A \subset B \subset A \implies A = B$. So $B$ is connected.

Comment: components are closed, connected sets need not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$A$ is connected so it is closed" is totally wrong !

Example : $]0,1[$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}$, but is not closed.

Comment: Okay, but isn't $A$ connected if $A$ (and the empty set) are both open and closed?

Comment: Yes, but in this definition, $A$ is open and closed in itself, that means for the induced topology (and for that topology, $A$ is always a closed and open subset of $A$). In the statement you gave, you look at the topological space $X$, and $A$ is just a subspace of this space : it can be closed, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: B \to \{0,1\}$ be continuous, where the doubleton has the discrete topology.
$f|A$ is constant by connectedness of $A$ and the assumption $A \subset B \subset \overline{A}$ implies that $A$ is dense in $B$ and as the image is Hausdorff, $f$ must be constant too as it coincides with a constant map on a dense subset and hence on the whole space. Ergo, $B$ is connected.